# Where can I find a good tutorial on iPhone/Objective-C multithreading?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, multithreading, cocoa

I'm just starting to use multithreading and was looking for a good explanation. I'm not sure if there are differences in how multithreading works on Macs and iPhones. What is a good link to tutorials with example code?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

A simple, but complete example is *[Multithreading in Cocoa](http://softpixel.com/~cwright/programming/threads/threads.cocoa.php)*.

And a related Stack Overflow question is *[NSOperation on the iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/830218)*.

Answer (score 11):

Once again, if I may promote my iPhone development course, I had a class devoted to multithreading last semester, covering basic threading, locking, dealing with the UI on the main thread, and NSOperationQueues, for which the class notes can be found [here](http://www.sunsetlakesoftware.com/sites/default/files/Spring2010CourseNotes/multithreading.html).  This fall semester that same class will be dominated by Grand Central Dispatch.

The video for the class [can be downloaded for free from iTunes U](https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/advanced-iphone-development-spring-2010/id407243032).

Answer (score 9):

Don't forget the official documentation from Apple: [Threading Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/)

You will find complete explanations and example code.

Answer (score 5):

- *[Cocoa Tutorial: NSOperation and NSOperationQueue](http://www.cimgf.com/2008/02/16/cocoa-tutorial-nsoperation-and-nsoperationqueue/)*
- *[Cocoa for Scientists (Part XXI): Multi-Threading Your App with NSOperation and NSOperationQueue](http://www.macresearch.org/node/4567)*
- *[Concurrent Operations Demystified](http://www.dribin.org/dave/blog/archives/2009/05/05/concurrent_operations/)*
- *[A Guide to Threading on Leopard](http://cocoasamurai.blogspot.com/2008/04/guide-to-threading-on-leopard.html)*

Answer (score 3):

A good and short tutorial on NSInvocationOperation is *[Loading Images Asynchronously on iPhone using NSInvocationOperation](http://tech.pro/tutorial/1011/loading-images-asynchronously-on-iphone-using-nsinvocationoperation)*.