# How does multithreading work in Objective-C on the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, multithreading

I'm confused about the concept of "threads" in iPhone development:

- Why are threads necessary / *useful*?
- How can threads be *used* in Objective-C?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where can I find a good tutorial on iPhone/Objective c multithreading?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1004845/where-can-i-find-a-good-tutorial-on-iphone-objective-c-multithreading)

Comment: These are very general questions... can you give a specific indication of what you're trying to achieve? Or are we just doing your homework for you?

Comment: @BradLarson You as a moderator are referring to a 'not constructive' question?!!? :|

Answer (score 6):

You need multi-threading in objective c because sometimes you need functions/code to run "in the background" (read: on another thread). For instance (but not explicitly) you might need to download large amounts of data off the internet (a picture, or a video).

In this case running the download on the 'main' thread will cause the iphone to freeze before the download is complete. So you use multi-threading to download the data AND let the iphone work all at the same time.

There are lots of ways to do multithreading in objective-c. To be honest you need to look it up yourself, we're not here to just spoonfeed you.

Things to look up are: `NSURLConnection` and the method `[self performSelector:onThread:...]`

Answer (score 0):

More simple...If you want to run some methods(processes) parallely you can use threads...One thread is doing one stuff while another doing other stuff... So u can use threads if you need something to be done when another thing is doing...
Example: Thread 1: sending request to server
Thread 2: preparing information(image,text etc) to be sent.
So in general this is the purpose of threads

Answer (score 0):

Recently, Apple suggests that programmers should move away from thread and use an alternative solution with more advantages, better performances and much more easier to implement; it's Concurrency Programming:
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091

Comment: These are not competing technologies. Threads are part of "Concurrency Programming" and need to be fully understood to successfully build multithreaded applications. Apple's documentation could be a bit misleading in this context when they proclaim "Migrating away from threads" or so.

Answer (score 0):

The recommended way to implement concurrency is using queues.

For those who just want to execute a method / block in a separate thread - use this code:

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
dispatch_async(queue, ^{
   [self longMehtod];
});
```

for further information read the [Concurrency Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html) from Apple