# Implementing multithread using XCode for IPhone

Tags: iphone, multithreading, xcode

Is there a way implement multi threading in IPhone using xcode? Could you refer me to few tuts that I could use.

Thanks and Regards

Abishek R Srikaanth

Comment: The response is in an other question : [good-tutorial-on-iphone-objective-c-multithreading](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1004845/where-can-i-find-a-good-tutorial-on-iphone-objective-c-multithreading)

Comment: Have you really tried Google?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where can I find a good tutorial on iPhone/Objective c multithreading?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1004845/where-can-i-find-a-good-tutorial-on-iphone-objective-c-multithreading)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way to implement multi-threading is probably going to be using NSOperationQueue. You subclass NSOperation, or create an NSBlockOperation with the code block you want to run in the background. Set a completion block if you need to be notified on the main thread when the background task finishes. Then add your operation to an NSOperationQueue and you're set! You can also set dependancies on the operation to run a series of events one at a time, or add many operations to the queue if you don't care what order they're executed in.

There are other ways of doing threading, but NSOperation is especially nice since it wraps everything up into a neat unit of work, where you're less likely to make shared memory mistakes, and also you can trust NSOperationQueue to look at the number of cores in your device and do the right thing when it comes to running many operations at once.