# How to use and where to use NSOperation and NSOperationQueue>

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [NSOperation on the iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/830218/nsoperation-on-the-iphone)

I am new to Objective-c Iphone, and I came to know about NSOperation and NSOperationQueue.
Where to use this and how can I use this? Can anyone give me explanations with any small example program?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 8):

This will surely help you - http://www.icodeblog.com/2010/03/04/iphone-coding-turbo-charging-your-apps-with-nsoperation/

Answer (score 3):

A quick Google turned up:

- The [Concurrency Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091), dealing with operations and threading
- The [NSOperationQueue](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperationQueue_class/Reference/Reference.html) class reference
- The (aptly named) [NSOperationSample](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/NSOperationSample/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10004184) example project, straight from Apple, and
- [A descriptive post](http://www.cimgf.com/2008/02/16/cocoa-tutorial-nsoperation-and-nsoperationqueue/) from the excellent blog "Cocoa Is My Girlfriend," with a small, well-explained example, complete with code snippets.