# Difference between Nsoperations and NSoperationqueues

Tags: ios

enter code hereWhat is  difference between NSoperations and NSoperationqueues?

Thanks
keerthi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The NSOperation class is an abstract class you use to encapsulate the code and data associated with a single task.

The NSOperationQueue class regulates the execution of a set of NSOperation objects. After being added to a queue, an operation remains in that queue until it is explicitly canceled or finishes executing its task.

you can also check these links..because they have given the nice answer:-

[Difference between NSOperation and NSInvocationOperation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12908886/difference-between-nsoperation-and-nsinvocationoperation)

http://www.raywenderlich.com/19788/how-to-use-nsoperations-and-nsoperationqueues